# Get all filenames in a directory created before input date

Tags: shell, files, timestamps

I have a directory containing lots of files. The output of `ls` command is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    427494 May 26 13:59 14_20150526065238928590_102.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup   2113592 May 26 14:00 14_20150526065238928590_105.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    429947 May 26 14:00 14_20150526065238928590_110.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    453831 May 27 14:00 14_20150526065238928590_112.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    551023 May 27 14:01 14_20150526065238928590_118.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup     60083 May 27 14:01 14_20150526065238928590_119.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    632324 May 28 03:38 14_20150526065238928590_160.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    735624 May 28 03:38 14_20150526065238928590_161.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup   2707507 May 28 03:40 14_20150526065238928590_162.txt
```

From the above list I want to retrieve file names those are created before input date:

> For eg: My input date is 20150528, I want the result: (created before 28th of May 2015)

```
14_20150526065238928590_102.txt
14_20150526065238928590_105.txt
14_20150526065238928590_110.txt
14_20150526065238928590_112.txt
14_20150526065238928590_118.txt
14_20150526065238928590_119.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find all files in the current directory and its subdirectories whose last modification time is earlier than 2015-05-28:

```
find . ! -newermt 20150527
```

If you only want files from the current directory and *not* its subdirectories, use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -newermt 20150527
```

#### How it works

- `find`

  This is one of unix's most useful commands when searching for files.
- `.`

  This tells `find` to start looking in the current directory.  You can replace this with any directory that you like.
- `!`

  This is logical-not: it inverts the test which follows.
- `-newermt 20150527`

  This is test for files whose modification time is newer than 2015-05-27.  Because of the preceding `!`, this test is inverted and it looks for files *not* newer than 2015-05-27.

  Note that "*not* newer than 2015-05-27" means the same as "created before 28th of May 2015".

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the result. The output contain ./ append before the filename. like ./14_20150526065238928590_105.txt. Can we remove the path from the result?

Comment: @fortune To remove the leading `./`, use: `find . ! -newermt 20150527 | sed 's|^./||'`

Comment: That is it. Great